# How can i save my seekbar position after closing the app process?

Tags: android

I'm trying to save the position of a `SeekBar` after closing the process, not only when I put the application in background, but even when i kill the process. How can I do it?

Comment: [Way to Go](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use shared preferences:

```
SharedPreference sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor e = sp.edit();
int seekbar = seekbar.getProgress();
e.putInt("BarPosition", seekbar).commit();
```

then whenever you load your view get it from shared pref:

```
int sp = mSharedPrefs.getInt("BarPosition", 0);
seekbar.setProgress(sp);
```

You can call these on `onPause()` method when app is in background/killed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `SharedPreferences` library. For example:

```
// If you are inside an activity:
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

// == OR == If you have a context reference:
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences("seekbarPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);


// To save your value:
int curPos = 25;
sharedPref.edit().putInt("seekbarPosition", curPos).apply();

// To get your value:
int pos = sharedPref.getInt("seekbarPosition", 0);
```

This values will be persisted in the app's cache, until they will be destroyed by the user itself (for example when it clears the app's cache) or when the app is uninstalled.